# backup and restore Logical volumes for glusterfs and kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, database-backups, glusterfs

I am working with kubernetes and i tried to dynamically provision volumes on top of gluster cluster and heketi through k8s pvc.

it can happen that my data will be corrupted or maybe lost so i need to know THE BEST WAY to backup and restore logical volumes (lv) for a running gluster cluster on top of kubernetes

Answer (score 0):

The best approach of doing glusterfs backup is by using geo-replication.

https://docs.gluster.org/en/v3/Administrator%20Guide/Geo%20Replication/